# Find whether a particular file path exists or not in java (not a regular search, looking for efficient algorithm)

Tags: java, algorithm, file, split

I am storing some outputs in the below format in my root directory
for instance,

```
/from_2012_07_17_01_apple_to_2012_07_23_05_apple/
```

The details inside this directory is generated by running a Java program

The first field is year the second is month, third is day, fourth is hour. This is the file that I have already stored in my root. The intention is to use it for later purpose.

In the later stage if I have a query that asks for the below

```
/from_2012_07_19_01_apple_to_2012_07_20_05_apple/
```

I would want to know that this has already appeared in the root directory as 19>17 and 20<23. I would like to identify this and make sure that I don't run the program again instead to reuse the same and then display the output directly to the user.I can do this by some manual work of splitting and comparing. But I am looking for some efficient algorithm for this.

```
EDITED
```

when user input is (from 19-20). .
I need to know  the existence of any of the below file

2012_07_17_01_apple_to_2012_07_23_01_apple,
2012_07_14_01_apple_to_2012_07_25_01_apple

If these two are there .. I need to choose the first file as the search space is less in that and that is effective ... Hence I am looking for this solution

Comment: have you profiled your program to identify a bottleneck????  SO questions are going downhill fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you have sub folders or not, but it seems to be the best algorithm which solve this problem is backtracking.

---

Well, just sort your folder names alphabetically, and insert your query into it sorted, and the insertSort will give you an i index back. After it, you create a part of the sorted list, witch contains indexes from 0 to i-1. From that point you can work only the 'to_*' part of the names. Sort the sub list alphabetically again (using to_* parts only), and insert the query string sorted again, which will give you a j index. In this list every folder indexed from j+1 to .length-1 contains the query folder. After it you have to find the shortest one, with splits or so. I do not think there's a much more efficient solution for this. You can read about the most abstract backtracking algorithm, it could be faster, but it's very complicated, if it could solve it at all.

Comment: I think I am not clear with my question.. Please refer to the edited question .. Thanks for your replies

Comment: So the folder names representing intervals. you have a list of intervals, and a single interval in your query. you have to find the shortest interval in the list which contains the interval in your query. Is this your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I started to delete this after comments, however I suppose it should be left to help clarify the problem.

---

You're trying too hard.  Step back...

```
String fname = createNameFromDates(... params ...); // returning "/from_2012_07_19_01_apple_to_2012_07_20_05_apple"
File target = new File(fname);
if (target.isDirectory()) {
   // directory exists...
} else {
   // create directory & data
}
```

Comment: `if (target.exists())` also works. I think it expresses the intent a bit better.

Comment: @Zong That will work, but it's not necessarily sufficient - it matches files.  It's better to say what you want in the code; to be as absolutely explicit as you can.  Will save you stress later.

Comment: You ppl are right .. But I dont want to see whether from_2012_07_19_01_apple_to_2012_07_20_01_apple directory exists .. I would like to know is there any other directory in the root file which is lesser than the from date which is (from_2012_07_19_01) and greater than (from_2012_07_20_01).. I hope I am clear with the point ...

Answer (score 0):

First, use **nio2** java7 tools, optimized and secure.

Then you can `split("_")` the file name and compare the fields `[n]` and `[n+m]`